# Why if-then statement isn't working?

Tags: python

This is the code that I made when I tried making an if-then statement but, it always defaults to else. Also i just started trying to code from online tutorials today.

```
print('yes or no?')

if sys.stdin.readline() == 'yes' : 
    print('Yay')
else : 
    print('Aww')
```

This is what happens:

```
Console:yes or no?

Me:yes

Console:Aww
```

I've been looking stuff up for half an hour and can't figure out how to fix this please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sys.stdin.readline()` reads a line which ends with '\n' (when you hit "enter").

So you need to remove this '\n' from the captured input using `strip()`.

```
print('yes or no?')

if sys.stdin.readline().strip() == 'yes' : 
    print('Yay')
else : 
    print('Aww')
```

I tried to explain and solve your specific problem but you could of course use `raw_input()` or `input()` (PY3) as mentioned in the other answer.

Comment: Ok, thanks because I was using numbers before with it and I did not have to add .stip() to the end of sys.stdin.readline but I didn't know you had to use it for strings

Comment: with numbers too, readline() always captures the \n when you hit enter. Try it in python console and you'll see.

Comment: @Crozear Probably before when using numbers, you were using `int()` and that removes trailing whitespace

Answer (score 1):

In python, getting the input of a user's string can be done via `input()` (or in python 2.7, use `raw_input()`).

If you include the code:

```
user_input = raw_input("yes or no?")
```

This will first print the string "yes or no?", then wait for user input (through stdin), then save it as a string named `user_input`.

So, you change your code to be:

```
user_input = raw_input("yes or no?")
if user_input == "yes":
    print("Yay")
else:
    print("Aww")
```

this should have the desired effect.

Comment: Ok that's a lot easier to do than remembering sys.stdin.readline().

Answer (score 0):

Ok I used user_input and input instead of sys.stdin.readline() on strings and i used it in a basic calculator here it is :

```
import random
import sys
import os


user_input = input("Would you like to add or subtract?")
if user_input == 'add' :
    print('What would you like to add?')
    plus1 = float(sys.stdin.readline())
    print('Ok so %.1f plus what?' % (float(plus1)))
    plus2 = float(sys.stdin.readline())
    print('%.1f plus %.1f equals %.1f' % (float(plus1),float(plus2), float(plus1+plus2)))
elif user_input == 'subtract' :
    print('What would you like to subtract?')
    minus1 = float(sys.stdin.readline())
    print('Ok so %.1f minus what?' % (float(minus1)))
    minus2 = float(sys.stdin.readline())
    print('%.1f minus %.1f equals %.1f' % (float(minus1), float(minus2), float(minus1 - minus2)))
    else :
        print('That is not one of the above options')
```

Thanks alot guys!